# why my double link insert algorithm does not work?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I have a task for double link insert algorithm,I have spent a lot time on doing it but still failed,the `sortLink` method still can not work,could anyone help me how to solve it?The code is listed as below:

- **Link.java**：

```
  public class Link {

    private int value;
    private Link next;
    private Link prev;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Link getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(Link next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
    public Link getPrev() {
        return prev;
    }
    public void setPrev(Link prev) {
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}
```

- **Test.java**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testLink();
    }


    public static void sortLink(Link headLink){

        Link curLink=null,preLink=null,nextLink=null,link=null,pLink=null;

        curLink=headLink.getNext();
        headLink.setNext(null);
        headLink.setPrev(null);

        while(curLink!=null){

            pLink=curLink;

            link=curLink.getNext();


            if(curLink.getValue()<headLink.getValue()){
                curLink.setNext(headLink);
                curLink.setPrev(headLink.getPrev());
                headLink=curLink;
            }else{

                preLink=headLink;
                nextLink=headLink.getNext();

                while(nextLink!=null&&nextLink.getValue()<curLink.getValue()){
                    preLink=nextLink;
                    nextLink=nextLink.getNext();
                    curLink.setPrev(pLink);
                }
                curLink.setNext(preLink.getNext());

                preLink.setNext(curLink);
            }
            curLink=link;
        }

        showFE(headLink);
        //showEF(curLink);
    }

    public static void testLink(){
        Link link1=new Link();
        link1.setValue(7);
        Link link2=new Link();
        link2.setValue(3);
        Link link3=new Link();
        link3.setValue(1);
        Link link4=new Link();
        link4.setValue(2);
        Link link5=new Link();
        link5.setValue(9);
        Link link6=new Link();
        link6.setValue(6);
        Link link7=new Link();
        link7.setValue(4);
        Link link8=new Link();
        link8.setValue(8);
        Link link9=new Link();
        link9.setValue(5);

        link1.setNext(link2);
        link1.setPrev(null);

        link2.setNext(link3);
        link2.setPrev(link1);

        link3.setNext(link4);
        link3.setPrev(link2);

        link4.setNext(link5);
        link4.setPrev(link3);

        link5.setNext(link6);
        link5.setPrev(link4);

        link6.setNext(link7);
        link6.setPrev(link5);

        link7.setNext(link8);
        link7.setPrev(link6);

        link8.setNext(link9);
        link8.setPrev(link7);

        link9.setPrev(link8);
        link9.setNext(null);

        showFE(link1);

        //showEF(link9);

        sortLink(link1);
    }


    //show node from front to end
    public static void showFE(Link link){
        while(link!=null){
            System.out.print(link.getValue()+"-->");
            link=link.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    //从尾至头显示链表
//  public static void showEF(Link link){
//      while(link!=null){
//          System.out.print(link.getValue()+"<--");
//          link=link.getPrev();
//      }
//      System.out.println();
//  }
}
```

The main method is `sortLink`,I have tried but I am not able to run this program correctly,

**it can output the result in order,but the relation between each link is not correct,so if we want to insert or remove some link,or show link from end to front, it will wrong.**

could anyone help me with correcting the insert algorithm?

Comment: It's working when I port the code over to C# without changing logic. What's your error?

Comment: @shree.pat18 it can output the result in order,but the relation between each link is not correct,so if we want to insert or remove some link,or show link from end to front, it will wrong,could you help me?

Comment: Don't use `curLink=headLink.getNext();`. If headLink itself is null, it will cause problem.